# Moving a relative range in Excel vba

Tags: vba, excel

So I'm trying to move a relative range in excel one cell down but i am getting an error trying to do so.
I basically got 2 Worksheets. 
The second one contains a couple of cells with hostnames. Below each hostname are more cells with names of locations. 
The first worksheet contains a button and whenever I click that button it asks me for a hostname and a new location. The idea is to find that hostname in the second worksheet and copy that whole list of locations one cell down without touching the actual hostname so that i can add the new location to the cell right below the hostname without losing any data.

This is my code so far which gives me an error:

```
Sub UpdateLocation(hostname As String, newLocation As String)
Dim rng1 As range
Dim rng2 As range
Dim tmpRng As range
Dim oldLocation As String

'find cells in both sheets
Set rng1 = FindCellInSheet(hostname, "ServerListe")
Set rng2 = FindCellInSheet(hostname, "History")

If Not rng1 Is Nothing And Not rng2 Is Nothing Then 'were both cells found?
    'change values in first sheet
    oldLocation = rng1.Offset(0, 1).Value
    rng1.Offset(0, 1).Value = newLocation
    rng1.Offset(1, 4).Value = oldLocation
    'change values in second sheet
    If Not IsEmpty(rng2.Offset(1, 0)) Then 'is there a history record yet?
        'select whole record until first empty cell
        Set tmpRng = range(rng2.Offset(1, 0), rng2.End(xlDown))
        'move content one cell down
        range(rng2.Offset(2, 0), rng2.Offset((1 + tmpRng.Rows.count), 0)).Value = tmpRng.Value
    End If
    'insert oldLocation into history
    rng2.Offset(1, 0).Value = oldLocation
Else
    'in case one or both cells weren't found
    MsgBox "'" & hostname & "' wurde nicht gefunden oder ist nur in einer Tabelle vorhanden."
End If
End Sub

Private Function FindCellInSheet(searchString As String, sheetName As String) As range
If Not IsEmpty(Trim(searchString)) Then 'remove spaces and check if cell is empty
    With Sheets(sheetName).UsedRange 'selects all cells with content
        'find searchString in specified sheet, case insensitive
        Set FindCellInSheet = .Find(What:=searchString, _
                                    LookIn:=xlValues, _
                                    LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                                    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                                    SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                                    MatchCase:=False)
    End With
End If
Exit Function
End Function
```

Everything is working finde besides the part where i try to select the range and move the whole lot one cell down.

I hope you guys can point me in the right direction.
Thank you in advance!

Edit:

```
        'select whole record until first empty cell
        Set tmpRng = range(rng2.Offset(1, 0), rng2.End(xlDown))
        'move content one cell down
        range(rng2.Offset(2, 0), rng2.Offset((1 + tmpRng.Rows.count), 0)).Value = tmpRng.Value
```

Those are the lines giving me an error.

Comment: What line errors out? It's hard to tell without some pictures...

Comment: I edited the lines giving me an error to the original post.

Comment: Your `range` and `rng2` are on different sheets.

Comment: That worked! Thank you very much, im quite new to vba so I'm still trying to figure stuff out.

Comment: You're welcome! I'll put it as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `range` and `rng2` are on different sheets.

**UPDATE**

When you type `Range`, then you effectively refer to whichever sheet happens to be active, so it's good idea to qualify Range with sheet name.